# How to sum all values in a vector or maps

Tags: vector, clojure, hashmap, sum

I have a vector of maps as follows:

[{:count 3} {:count 5} {:count 8}]

How do I go about summing :count values to obtain one value in Clojure?

Answer (score 9):

```
(def v [{:count 3} {:count 5} {:count 8}])

(reduce #(+ %1 (:count %2)) 0 v);; => 16
```

Or

```
(apply + (map :count v));; => 16
```

You need to learn how functions are combined, then the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
(reduce #(+ %1 (%2 :count)) 0 [{:count 3} {:count 5} {:count 8}])
```

Answer (score 1):

And another one:

```
(transduce (map :count) + 0 [{:count 2} {:count 12}])
```

Answer (score -1):

Is

```
(reduce + 
    (map :count v))
```

not another valid syntax
for summing :count values of vector v of {:count } maps?

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.